# Group by 4 different levels and total numeric field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm querying a financial database that has the following information:

- Company ID
- Fiscal Year
- Fiscal Period
- Account
- Amount

I want to group the data by the first four fields and show a grouped total of amount.

I tried the GROUP BY but that doesn't seem to work.

In my screenshot, I'm trying to get rows 1-10 to show as one line, as all the information is the same except for the amount.

[image]

Here's my code:

```
SELECT        Erp.GLJrnDtl.Company, Erp.GLJrnDtl.FiscalYear, 
Erp.GLJrnDtl.FiscalPeriod, Erp.GLJrnDtl.BalanceAcct, 
Erp.GLJrnDtl.BookDebitAmount - Erp.GLJrnDtl.BookCreditAmount AS Amount

FROM          Erp.GLJrnDtl INNER JOIN
Erp.GLPeriodBal ON Erp.GLJrnDtl.Company = 
Erp.GLPeriodBal.Company AND Erp.GLJrnDtl.FiscalYear = 
Erp.GLPeriodBal.FiscalYear AND Erp.GLJrnDtl.FiscalPeriod = 
Erp.GLPeriodBal.FiscalPeriod AND 
Erp.GLJrnDtl.BalanceAcct = 
Erp.GLPeriodBal.BalanceAcct

WHERE        (Erp.GLJrnDtl.FiscalYear >= 2018) AND (Erp.GLJrnDtl.Company 
= N'011') and (Erp.GLJrnDtl.SegValue1 = N'310050')

GROUP BY Erp.GLJrnDtl.Company, Erp.GLJrnDtl.FiscalYear, 
Erp.GLJrnDtl.FiscalPeriod, Erp.GLJrnDtl.BalanceAcct, 
Erp.GLJrnDtl.PostedDate, Erp.GLJrnDtl.BookDebitAmount, 
Erp.GLJrnDtl.BookCreditAmount, Erp.GLJrnDtl.SegValue1,                                
Erp.GLPeriodBal.BalanceAmt
```

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images. (And I can't read that tiny image text on my phone.)

Comment: I can't even read it on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

```
select company_id, fiscal_year, fiscal_period, account, sum(amount) 
from table  group by company_id, fiscal_year, fiscal_period, account
```

You need to leave out the field you want to aggregate outside the group by line

Answer (score 0):

Please explain why this does not do what you want:

```
select Company_ID, Fiscal_Year, Fiscal_Period, Account, sum(Amount)
from t
group by Company_ID, Fiscal_Year, Fiscal_Period, Account;
```

This is the "obvious" query.  The query in the image is much more complicated.

Comment: I can't explain it. I don't have any experience with SQL but there's nobody else I can ask besides you guys and google. I barely have enough knowledge to put together this query, hence why I'm asking.

Thanks for the help.